# Clunking noise when braking -- possibly bad CV axle?

Tags: toyota, sienna, cv-boot, cv-axle, front-wheel-drive

Our 2007 Sienna XLE V6 had its CV boots replaced not too long ago by the dealer but just recently when turning slightly to the right when driving the car makes a very bad clanking sound + vibrating steering wheel. It gradually increased until one day it just stopped. Now, only sometimes the entire car vibrates and clanks when turning about 5 degrees to the right while driving...on occasion. Additionally, when alternating from braking to accelerating there is a clank similar to a bad U-joint.

The steering feels very loose too now by the way. Owned this car from 0 miles. Any help is gladly appreciated!

Comment: You're back! ;)  Can't say I've had this problem myself, but how many miles are on the car?

Comment: @Cullub 128k miles on the clock. Yes I am back :)

Comment: Also have someone check your engine mounts, serious vibrations and clunking could be coming from one or more failed engine mounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially reading your description it sounded like a worn CV joint or joints. Were normally you'd notice the clunking sound more when the steering is turned one way or the  other, and your accelerating slightly.

However as you mention this noise has now mostly gone and there are different symptoms e.g 'very loose steering', you need to stop using the vehicle immediately for your own and others safety and have it inspected, as it sounds like there may not only be an issue with a CV joint etc, but also with a suspension joint/link or the steering rack itself, as a bad CV joint alone wouldn't make the steering feel loose.

Comment: Oh boy...the dealer failed the inspection for something with the steering rack 2 years back. Now we have it inspected at our local mechanics shop where they dont say a thing...I will have it checked soon though, as we thought the dealer was making its money worth of service

Comment: Have it looked at by another mechanic if you can, explain all the symptoms you mention here, there are mechanics and mechanics unfortunately, some are not as particular or as well informed as others.

Comment: Yes, I know a few mechanics and I will check tie rods too, but my suspicion lies on the part the dealer told me about. I was very surprised to climb underneath the car to find brand smacking new boots...hey its been dealer maintained up until 10k miles ago.

Comment: Perhaps the dealer mechs just thought that regreasing and fitting new CV boots would have been sufficient to save the CV joints, however once a CV boot has been torn for a short while roads grit etc just acts like grinding paste on the CV bearings, so they'll wear out far quicker than they normally would, even if re-greased. If you're ok and know what to look for with regards checking suspension/steering parts etc, also check top & bottom ball joints and associated wishbone bushes etc, as all these components if worn or failed will lead to a loose steering feel.